# Number of integer squares in finite arithmetic progression.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

How many square values can $u+vb$ take where $u,v\in\Bbb N$ are fixed and $u\approx v^2$ and $b$ varies from $0$ to $v$?

Comment: What is $u≈v^2" supposed to mean?

Comment: A diagram would serve a long way to make this question more clear

Comment: $u=\Theta(v^2)$ similar in growth.

Comment: There are about $(\sqrt{2}-1)v$ squares between $v^2$ and $2v^2$, so even assuming equidistribution of the squares among the residue classes $\pmod{v}$ (that does not hold for sure since there is no square $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, for instance) the expected number of squares in that range is $\sqrt{2}-1<1$.